# How can I address dynamic text inside a buttom?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, programming-languages, dynamic-text

I have a "handmade" button (_btn as instance name), with only a dynamicText inside (or can I say one dynaticText for each of the four button modes). The dynamicText for Up mode has an instance name of "_text".
So if I am working on the AS of the movieClip that contains the button, how can I  address the text of the dynamic text?

```
package  {
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.display.SimpleButton;

public class container extends MovieClip {
    var _btn:button;

    public function container() {
        _btn= new button;
        this.addChild(_btn);
        switch (_btn._text.text)
        {
            case "a": doAFunction();
            case "b": doBFunction();
            case "c": doCFunction();
        }

    }

}

}
```

What is the problem with my code?

```
Access of possibly undefined property _text through a reference with static type flash.display:SimpleButton.
```

Comment: Is the `container` class your document class?

Comment: Yes, it is..... If you means the AS class of the flash file. ^^"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a button symbol in flash professional, the symbol becomes an instance of `SimpleButton`. If you want to access the display objects that you've created in the button symbol, e.g dynamic textfield, you have to access it via the `SimpleButton` object's `upState`, `overState`, `downState` and `hitTestState` properties.

I've created a utility function that you can include in your project to get dynamic textfields. The function is called `getDTFFromSB()`(get dynamic textfield from simplebutton).

The function takes the arguments `simpleButton` and `state`. The `simpleButton` argument is obviously for the `SimpleButton` object in question, and the `state` argument is for specifying which state property(`upState`,`overState`,`downState` and `hitTestState`) the textfield is located on with the respective string values: "up", "over", "down" and "hit".

The function returns an `Object` object that is either a `TextField` object, `Vector.<TextField` object or null.

Here is the utility function getDTFFromSB():

```
package utils
{
    import flash.display.DisplayObject;
    import flash.display.DisplayObjectContainer;
    import flash.display.SimpleButton;
    import flash.text.TextField;

    /**
     * get dynamic textfield from simple button
     */
    public function getDTFFromSB(simpleButton:SimpleButton, state:String = "up"):Object
    {
        var returnObject:Object;

        var displayObject:DisplayObject;

        switch(state)
        {
            case "up" : displayObject = simpleButton.upState;
            case "over" : displayObject = simpleButton.overState;
            case "down" : displayObject = simpleButton.downState;
            case "hit" : displayObject = simpleButton.hitTestState;

        }// end switch

        if(displayObject is TextField)
        {
            returnObject = displayObject;
        }
        else if(displayObject is DisplayObjectContainer)
        {
            var doc:DisplayObjectContainer = displayObject as DisplayObjectContainer;
            var textFields:Vector.<TextField> = new Vector.<TextField>();

            for(var i:uint = 0; i < doc.numChildren; i++)
            {
                if(doc.getChildAt(i) is TextField) 
                textFields.push(doc.getChildAt(i));

            }// end for

            if(textFields.length == 0) returnObject = null
            else if(textFields.length == 1) returnObject = textFields[0]
            else if(textFields.length > 1) returnObject = textFields;

        }
        else
        {
            returnObject = null;

        }// end else

        return returnObject;

    }// end function

}// end package
```

I also created an example of its use. In the library I have a button symbol that I exported for actionscript. The button symbol has one dynamic textfield in its "up" state and its `text` property's value is "a". Here is the code in the document class:

```
package
{
    import utils.getDTFFromSB;
    import flash.display.SimpleButton;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.text.TextField;

    public class Main extends Sprite
    {
        private var _myButton:SimpleButton;

        public function Main()
        {
            if(stage) init()
            else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

        }// end function

        private function init(e:Event = null):void
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

            _myButton = new MyButton();
            addChild(_myButton);

            var returnedObject:Object = getDTFFromSB(_myButton);

            var textField:TextField;

            if(returnedObject is TextField)
            {
                textField = TextField(returnedObject);

            }
            else if(returnedObject is Vector.<TextField>)
            {
                textField = Vector.<TextField>(returnedObject)[0];

            }
            else if(returnedObject == null)
            {
                throw new Error("null value returned from getDTFFromSB() method");

            }// end if

            trace(textField.text) // ouput: a

        }// end function

    }// end class

}// end package
```

When I create a new instance of the button symbol, called `_myButton`, I parse it to the `getDTFFromSB()` function and store the returned object in a local object, called `returnedObject`. Then I use if statements to determine the type of the return object, and if it is a `TextField` object`, I store it in a local`TextField`object. Now if I trace the`text`property of the`TextField` object I get "a".

Answer (score 0):

"button" is not known in this script - if you want to create a standard button, use `new Button()` (with capital B).

and i think Button has no text attribute but one that's called "label".

try using `_btn.label`.

Comment: Thank you, but ...actually, "button" is just a class I made so it's not that I making a new button inside AS file. T_T And the problem is that I want to compare, modify and so on with the dynamic text inside the button.

Comment: what do you want to compare? which button is pressed? then do this in the eventlistener ...

Answer (score 0):

```
package  {
  import flash.display.MovieClip;
  //import flash.display.SimpleButton;
  import fl.controls.Button

  public class container extends MovieClip {
    var _btn:button;
    public function container() {
      _btn= new button;
      this.addChild(_btn);
      switch (_btn.label)
      // switch (_btn._text.text)
      {
          case "a": doAFunction();
          case "b": doBFunction();
          case "c": doCFunction();
      }

    }

  }

}
```

Comment: Why my Flash only has core inside mx? I don't have controls.?? 1172: Definition mx.controls:Button could not be found.

Comment: Ah sorry I used the Flex 3 libraries. I adjusted my code for flash cs4 fl.controls.Button

Comment: @Brian Lin Without you posting the code for your Button class you made this is the best anyone will be able to offer you.